# Awk command for summing up columns of a file

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a file (old.dat) which has let's say 20 columns. Now, I want a different file (new.dat) containing 2 columns namely x and y say, where y is the sum of all the even columns of old.dat file i.e., y = $2+$4+$6+...(of the old.dat file, X will remain same )

Is there any efficient way to write a 'awk' command for this purpose? 
N.B. I don't want to write every time $2+$4+$6 like this, may be a variable instead?

old.dat:

```
-36.0331 1 -36.0331 2 -36.0331 3 -36.0331 2 -36.0331 1 -36.0331 2
```

new.dat (desired one)

```
-36.0331  11
```

this is just the one row of the file.

Comment: post also the contents of old.dat and desired new.dat

Comment: @amdixon: Yes, I edited my question. Please have a look of the file format.

Comment: old.dat only has 12 columns - does this mean the number of columns is variable ?

Comment: Ok, may be I am confusing you. Let's say in this particular case, I want to get the new.dat file where the 2nd column will be the sum of all the even column in old.dat file. Column no. is not varying, it remains same.

Comment: What about 1st column in result `-36.0331`? Isn't it sum of all odd columns?

Comment: No, I don't want to change my X column in new.dat file.  X column will remain same as old.dat file X column. Only the Y column in new.dat file will be the sum of all the even columns of old.dat file. @anubhava

Comment: Use perl. Seriously, stop using awk, it's 2015.

Comment: could do this in so many ways, nothing wrong with awk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `for` loop can be used.

```
awk '{s=0;for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2)s+=$i;print$1,s}' old.dat > new.dat
```

Comment: Many thanks, that's the command I was looking for. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `gnu-awk 4` without for loop

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="[ \t]+|[\n]"; c=0; s=0}
c==0{first=$0;}
c%2{s+=$0;}
{c++}
RT=="\n"{print first, s; c=0; s=0}
END{if(c!=0) print first, s}' old.dat
```

with input file

```
-36.0331 1 -36.0331 2 -36.0331 3 -36.0331 2 -36.0331 1 -36.0331 2
A 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19  20
B 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
```

you get

```
-36.0331 11
A 100
B 300
```